# How to resolve peer certificate error in php

Tags: php, laravel, ssl

Trying to get the contents of a file in Laravel PHP using `file_get_contents()` as shown in the snippet below. The code is working fine on my local server with valet but when I upload to the production server I get the following error:

> ErrorException: file_get_contents(): Peer certificate CN='one46.com' did not match expected CN='one46.comhttp'

```
$verification_request['face'] = [
   'proof' => base64_encode(file_get_contents($this->faceFile))
];
```

In the code snippet $this->faceFile is a reference to the file URL.

Comment: What does `$this->faceFile` contain? You speak about a file but you're clearly establishing a network connection :-?

Comment: $this->face File contains a url to an image file

Answer (score 2):

if using file_get_contents over HTTP you can set many connection options via context. One of them is to ignore SSL problems.
try this:

```
$context = stream_context_create([
  "ssl" => [
    "verify_peer" => FALSE,
    "verify_peer_name" => FALSE,
  ],
  "http" => [
    "ignore_errors" => TRUE,
  ],
]);
file_get_contents($theURL, NULL, $context);
```